# Data type mismatch in criteria expression when attempting to save data to a database

Tags: vb.net

```
        str = "Insert Into Bookee([Staff] , [Full Name], [Contact Number], [Email] , [Resource], [Period], [Date])Values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection) 'This allows me to assign values to the fields using what the user input'
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Staff", CType(CBStaffName.Checked, Boolean))) 'This adds the value of the checkbox in the matching field and sets the variable type'
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Full Name", CType(TxtBoxFullName.Text, String))) 'This adds the value of the each textbox in the matching field and sets the variable type'
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Contact Number", CType(TxtBoxContactNumber.Text, String))) 'This adds the value of the each textbox in the matching field and sets the variable type'
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Email", CType(TxtBoxEmail.Text, String))) 'This adds the value of the each textbox in the matching field and sets the variable type'
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Period", CType(TxtBoxPeriod.Text, Integer))) 'this adds the Period textboxes value to the database'
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Date", CType(DateTimePicker1.Text, Date)))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Resource", CType(TxtBoxResource.Text, String)))
```

I have attempted to save the data to the database but when attempting to i get the error ' data type mismatch in criteria' however the data types match to those in the database and i have used the exact same code in another from excluding the staff and period fields and this works fine

Comment: First, you do not need to convert `TextBox.Text` because it is already string.  Dont use `DateTimePicker1.Text` but use the `.Value` and no conversion is need for that one.  There is more information in the exception telling you the Type which wold narrow things down.  Please read [ask] and take the [TOUR]

Comment: Period and Resource are out of order.

Comment: CheckBox.Checked is a Boolean. No CType necessary.

Answer (score 2):

OleDb wants your parameters in the exact order in which they are specified through the placeholders list. You have changed the position of the Resource parameter. In this way the value for the *TxtBoxResource* textbox  goes to the Date field and, of course, that's hardly a valid date.

The fields list is specified as

```
[Staff], [Full Name], [Contact Number], [Email], [Resource], [Period], [Date]
```

so you should add the parameters in that exact order.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Staff", CBStaffName.Checked)) 
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Full Name", CType(TxtBoxFullName.Text, String)))
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Contact Number", CType(TxtBoxContactNumber.Text, String)))
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Email", CType(TxtBoxEmail.Text, String))) 
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Resource", CType(TxtBoxResource.Text, String)))
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Period", CType(TxtBoxPeriod.Text, Integer)))
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Date", CType(DateTimePicker1.Text, Date)))
```

May I suggest you a concise syntax with more precision in defining the datatype of the parameter?

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("Staff", OleDbType.Boolean).Value = CBStaffName.Checked
cmd.Parameters.Add("Full Name", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = TxtBoxFullName.Text
cmd.Parameters.Add("Contact Number", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = TxtBoxContactNumber.Text
cmd.Parameters.Add("EMail", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = TxtBoxEmail.Text
cmd.Parameters.Add("Resource", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = TxtBoxResource.Text
cmd.Parameters.Add("Period", OleDbType.Integer).Value = CType(TxtBoxPeriod.Text, Integer)
cmd.Parameters.Add("Date". OleDbType.Date).Value =  DateTimePicker1.Value
```

As noted by Plutonix in its comment there is no need to call CType on values that are already of the required type

Answer (score 1):

Just a small addition to Steve's excellent answer. When you are dealing with a text box, results are unpredictable. When you require an integer maybe a drop down list or test your value thusly...

```
 Dim itgPeriod As Integer
 If Int32.TryParse(txtFirst.Text, itgPeriod) Then
        cmd.Parameters.Add("Period", OleDbType.Integer).Value = itgPeriod
 Else
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number in the Period Box.")
        Exit Sub
 End If
```